# How do I force a Codeigniter route to return a 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, url-routing

Basically I'm trying to make the admin section of a website harder to find. I have a Controller named built like this

```
class Admin extends MY_Controller{ // actions below
```

I like having the name Admin for the controller since it tells any future developer that might work on the site that this controller contains the admin section of the website.

However; as an extra layer of security, I don't want the admin section reachable by simply typing into a browser www.theDomain.com/admin. I would much rather that any route starting with "admin" return my standard 404 response.

I was hoping this could be achieved in the routes file with something like

```
$route['admin'] = 'error/404';
```

I would even accept being able to do this in the constructor of my controller. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Make sure you're not relying on attackers being unable to guess your admin URL as your security. Obfuscation != security. Implement your security with the assumption that attackers know the URL.

Comment: What version of Ci you using?

Comment: @heikkila this is not my only for of security I am using. This is an added layer to the security of the website.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I'm using 3.0.3

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Perhaps you could call `show_404()` in your controller method.

Comment: How would I know that the url was for /admin and not for the url I want to allow

Comment: You could load the URL helper, do `$current = current_url();` and check to see if `/admin` is found. If so, then call `show_404()`.

Comment: I'm guessing either you don't know, or codeigniter doesn't have this, but is there a way to just get the path, or even better the path as an array of string where each subfolder is an entry in the array?

Comment: This is not the answer to this particular question. He is asking to make admin panel securer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different Class name for Admin Controller like "Admin48957". In this case, only who knows this Class Name can access the admin section by typing www.theDomain.com/admin48957. (This is the strategy of many modern CMSs. i.e. prestashop)

If you force return it 404. Then you also could not access by yourself.

But if you still want to return 404. You can use show_404() CodeIgniter function.